# About Hartshorne's Proposition 1.10

Tags: algebraic-geometry, proof-explanation, krull-dimension, dimension-theory-algebra

This is from Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry:

[image]

1. I don't understand how he concludes that $\text{height } m=n$. I agree that $\overline{Z_0}\subset...\subset\overline{Z_n}$ is maximal and gives rise to a maximal chain of primes in $A(\overline{Y})$ with $m$ as the greatest element. But that is just *one* maximal chain; if we wanted to conclude $\text{height }m=n$, we would have to check *all possible* maximal chains involving $m$, right?
2. I don't see the need to use heights. Isn't it possible to speak only in topological terms? Here is my attempt to prove Proposition 1.10:

> Let $n=\dim \overline{Y}$ and $S_0\subset...\subset S_n$ a maximal chain of irreducible, closed subsets of $\overline{Y}$. In particular, by the subset topology, $S_i=\overline{Y}\cap C_i$ for some closed $C_i\subset\mathbb{A}^n$ (Furthermore, since $S_i$ is irreducible, so must be $C_i$). Defining $D_i:=Y\cap C_i$, we also have that $D_0\subset...\subset D_n$ is a maximal chain of irreducible, closed subsets of $Y$. This means $\dim \overline{Y}=n\leq \dim Y$. The reverse inequality is trivial.

Is this correct?

Comment: His proof îs incorrect, he makes ți appear to ne a strictly topological fact. I would just cut him some slack, it's not a bad book, but luckily, there are lots of other sources nowadays.  Somehow, you should be able to start with any point in the maximal chain, so with a point in $Y$, which apriori is not clear why. I think it has to do with  some ring being catenary.

Comment: @orangeskid, I just can't see what step of the proof is wrong. How did you find the mistake?

Comment: You cannot be sure that $S_0$ is in $Y$, and that is the problem. Remember, $S_0$ is a one-point set.

Comment: @orangeskid, I see...

Comment: About your comment on catenary rings, I don't know if it answers the question. The maximal chain $\overline{Z_0}\subset...\subset\overline{Z_n}$ corresponds to a chain of prime ideals in $A(\overline{Y})$ begining with a minimal prime $p$ and ending with a maximal $m$, specific ones. What If we take another minimal prime $q\subset m$, and take a maximal chain $q\subset...\subset m$? How do we know it has the same length? I think the catenary property does not guarantee that.

Comment: you are right, it's not the catenary notion,  it's that you can start from any maximal ideal.,

Comment: Do you have [Silverman's](http://www.paris8.free.fr/Silverman,%20Advanced%20Topics%20in%20the%20Arithmetic%20of%20Elliptic%20Curves-ilovepdf-compressed.pdf)  Adv-AEC ?

Comment: Do you have a right proof now? I also have the question 1 as you.

Comment: @yuan, yes. In short, the answer to question 1 is that all maximal chains of $A(\overline{Y})$ have the same length. But this is not trivial. It relies on the fact that all maximal chains in $k[x_1,...,x_n]$ have length $n$ and consequently all chains in $A(\overline{Y})=k[x_1,...,x_n]/I(\overline{Y})$ (the fact that $I(\overline{Y})$ is prime is also important)

Comment: @yuan The claim about $k[x_1,...,x_n]$ is proven in Proposition 1 here https://mathstrek.blog/2020/05/01/commutative-algebra-43/#:~:text=If%20A%20is%20a%20catenary%20ring%20which%20is%20a%20local,chains%20have%20the%20same%20length.

Comment: @yuan you can check the claim about $A(\overline{Y})$ yourself once you're convinced of Proposition 1.

Comment: @rmdmc89, thank you.